# How can I secure myself from updating another object over current object by mistake?

Tags: c#, java, .net, design-patterns

Can you suggest me a way that would prevent me from such a case when I am working with reference types?

```
var someCost = new Cost( Price: new Price(1000, "USD")
                        , CostType: "Type-A") ;

var candyCost = new Cost();

// Initialize candyCost.Price
candyCost.Price = someCost.Price; //Now candyCost Price is referencing 
                                 // price of someCost; 

// (.......)
// Some logic and code here
//and I forgot that I was referencing to someCost object's price object
//and I do stupid mistake:

candyCost.Price.Value = 5000; //Now I believe I have updated candyCost price 
                              //but I have also updated someCost!!
```

Rest of the story is about debugging to find out why someCost's Price is updated.

I wanted to simplify the problem with this example. I hope if you get my meaning.

***Question***: Can you recommend me a way to secure myself from repeating such a mistake? any design patterns when it comes to updating values that are on reference types.

Comment: Is this really `java` related?

Comment: I thought it could cover Java guys opinions as well, isn't it?

Comment: do *"OO over immutable objects"*.  A lot of problems  suddenly becomes non-issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `Price` object should be immutable - this will force you to assign a new `Price` object instead of changing the price of an existing one, hence avoiding the side effect.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want to achieve with this line:

```
 candyCost.Price = someCost.Price;
```

Do you want to say, that `candyCost` and `someCost` have the same price *at this moment* or that they *always* have the same price?

If you just want to initialize `candyCost.Price` with a value that is *equal* to `someCost.Prize`, than you should clone the `Price` instance:

```
 candyCost.Price = new Price(someCost.Price); // copy constructor pattern inside
```

(of course you have to implement the constructor)

Comment: +1 for the good question! You are right, I should have stressed the main purpose. And the purpose is as you said, to initialize candyCost.Price with a value that is equal to someCost.Prize

Answer (score 1):

By **never** creating two local variables that represent the *same thing*.

Comment: He's asking if there's a way of protecting against that though, with some pattern or construct, no?

Comment: Well it is above everything is a matter coding discipline. That is the pattern.

Comment: The OP's example doesn't have two local variables that represent the same thing.

Comment: Yes, he does. `candyCost` and `someCost`

Comment: I may be mistaken but those are different `Cost` objects, it's the two `Price` objects that have the reference problem in question

Answer (score 1):

Create a deep copy of the class Price by implementing the IClonnable interface. Then when you assign the price you would say

```
a.Price = b.Price.Clone(); // will return a new object of the price after assigning the internal value types
```

or

```
  Class Cost{
  private Price _price;

        public Price PriceValue
        {
            get { _price.Clone(); }
            set { _price = value; }
        }
       }
```

this way you will never forget

hence you cannot access _price field directly, unless you call the Getter property which will eventually return a deep copy of the Price

Comment: But if you remember that you need to clone, then you don't need to worry. Whatif I forget to clone? This is what I am trying to secure myself from mustafabar.

Comment: Then use a Getter propert for the price, and inside it make your clone.. check the edit

Comment: @pencilClone - There is no universal prevent-from-stupid-bugs design pattern. Unfortunatly, I must say.

Comment: In this example there are ways to stop this bug happening though (but not by using `IClonable` alone)

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd suggest using a `struct` (value-type) instead of a `class` (reference type).  That way it's not possible to refer to the same instance, because there's no 'reference', the value itself is stored :)

You could also have the properties of the `Price` type read-only, and set only by the constructor.  That way you can reference another copy, but that's no problem - they'll both stay at the same value because to set to a new value you'd need to create a new object.

Comment: -1 Sorry I had to do it. That is really bad. Changing design so that you do not make one mistake? So you pay all **boxing overhead** just for that?

Comment: @Aliostad - There isn't enough info in the questsion to determine whether Price should be a struct or a class.  But there is no boxing involved in the sample code even if it is a struct.  I don't think your -1 is justified for that reason.

Comment: @Aliostad - I don't know what you're talking about.  `structs` exist for a reason, and the second option (readonly + constructor) is used all over the place.  The question itself asks which designs to use to avoid his problem, and that's *exactly* what I gave examples of.  Please reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

You want a by-value behaviour for the Price property. The getter should return a copy of the Price object.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing it.

1. Use immutable types - e.g. String in Java, and all the primitive wrappers
2. Use copy constructors to copy objects instead of referencing them

Immutability might seem like quite a painfully restrictive method at first but actually it's quite common and enforces what you are trying to do quite well.

Using copy constructors means you have to make sure that whenever you return an object (e.g. from a getter) you actually create a new object, similarly whenever you use a passed in object (e.g. setter) you need to copy it.

Answer (score 0):

Make Cost.Price read-only using {get; private set;}
Add an new method to Cost called SetPrice which takes a Price and creates a new Price instance

```
SetPrice(Price price)
{
    this.Price = price.Clone();
}
```

You will need to make Price implement IClonnable

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language, you can do operator overloading. So, overload the assignment operator (`=`) and perform a deep clone in the overloaded operator body.